Why does Chrome select text from separate divs instead of the current div?
Consider the following html:


<div style="user-select:none;position:absolute;top:10px;border:1px solid gray;height:100px;width:150px">
    <div style="user-select:text;position:absolute;top:10px">One</div>
    <div style="user-select:text;position:absolute;top:30px">Two Three</div>
</div>



If I double click (or triple click) on the word Two, I would expect Two Three be selected - as these words are in the same div.  But Chrome instead selects One and Two - words different divs.  Safari also does this.
Firefox, on the other hand, does it correctly (in my opinion) and selects Two Three.
Is there a way to modify the behavior so that it selects words in its own div?
P.S. Video of the behavior side by side.

Actually, when you triple click the text two it selects the two & three. I have tested in chrome.

Add a tabular display type for child divs - display: table. This will prevent text selection in "neighboring" divs at absolute positioning.
You can also use a flexible display type for this purpose - display: flex.


div > div {
  display: table;
}
<div style="user-select:none;position:absolute;top:10px;border:1px solid gray;height:100px;width:150px">
    <div style="user-select:text;position:absolute;top:10px">One</div>
    <div style="user-select:text;position:absolute;top:30px">Two Three</div>
</div>



